# How to run an script automatically once I check the previous finish?

Tags: bash, grid, jobs

I have to do several simulation in the grid of my job, but I can do it only one by one (otherwise the grid will give to my jobs less priority). So, I need to run one job and after I check that it is done, send the new one.

To send a job I have to run

```
run -file test.cfg
```

and to check if it is done, I have to run:

```
run -status test.cfg
```

where I receive a message showing me if the job is done. I want to run a job once I check the status and it is done.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the problem here?  Why can't you just run the job after checking the status?  I can't find a `bash` command called "run", where did that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a script along these lines would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a jobs=(task1.cfg task2.cfg task3.cfg);

for job in ${jobs[@]}; do
    # Start job
    run -file $job;
    # Wait for job to complete
    while [ "$(run -status $job)" != "COMPLETE" ]; do
            if [ "$(run -status $job)" == "FAILED" ]; then
                echo "Job $job failed" >&2;
                exit -1;
            fi;
            sleep 10m;
    done;
done;
```

Here we define a list of tasks to be run and loop through each of them, starting the job and waiting until it has completed before going onto the next task. It checks the running task status  every 10 minutes. It does some error checking to exit if the job has failed. Note the above has not been fully tested.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
run -file test.cfg ; run -status test.cfg
```

This will run the second command after the first one finished. This does not check for any kind of success.

A better way would be to check if the previous command returned with successful return code (i.e `$?=0`)

```
run -file test.cfg && run -status test.cfg
```

In this example `&&` means "run second command only if first return with 0 (i.e. success)

Lastly, if you want a meaningful message if the first command failed:

```
run -file test.cfg && run -status test.cfg || echo "first command execution failed"
```

The above means "run first command, and (`&&`) if successful run second command, else (`||`) echo error message